# Multiple DB's in 1 AWS RDS Server PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, aws-rds-data-service

Current Situation: We have 5-10 environments that we spin up for our developers during development (as needed) for them to push code changes to and test their changes in a "remote" environment. These environments are separate from your standard integration, staging, sandbox, etc environments.

Our current process is to run PostgreSQL with our "golden seed" on ECS containers in these environments. We'd like to get away from this.

One approach we're investigating is to instead have a singular RDS server with some type of environment-label separate DBs on that one RDS server for all these development "remote" environments to connect to.

Is this possible? What are my pro's and con's to using a single RDS server to house ~10 PostgreSQL DB's?

Research solutions on StackOverflow to this problem. I just haven't came across a clear cut why or why this shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Pros for all on one server

- better utilization in low util environments
- Cheaper for most monitoring tools like Datadog that are usually per host

Cons

- Noisy neighbors
- can’t do incremental updates